# Orbeon sql server user password reset

Tags: sql-server, tomcat7, orbeon

I had an administrator accident reset the sql server password of the Orbeon 4.6 user, in sql server 2008R2. Now none of the forms from Orbeon Server will post. Keep getting "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'orbeon_form_definition', database 'orbeon', schema 'dbo'"No one remembers the old password to change it back.

Trying to find out how I can go into Orbeon? or Tomcat to change the password for the user account that connects to SQL Server for the Orbeon database. Not familiar with Orbeon or how it works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbeon uses a container managed datasource. In `${TOMCAT_DIR}/conf/server.xml` there should be an entry like this where you can change the password:

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/sqlserver"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    initialSize="3"
    maxActive="10"
    maxIdle="20"
    maxWait="30000"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    poolPreparedStatements="true"
    validationQuery="select 1"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    username="orbeon"
    password="orbeon"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://server"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup just restore the backup in [SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx), if the data hasn't changed your done.  Otherwise go to the restored Orbeon database the user and overwrite the value in the current database.  Make sure you do a backup first incase you make a mistake.